# GRANT CREATE only on specific schema to specific role SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-grant

I'm looking to GRANT all sorts of CREATE statements on specific schemas in my DB for specific members of a role;
Here's my current setup, I have:

- Schema A
- Schema B
- Role A
- Role B
- SQL Login A
- SQL Login B
- Schema A is owned by Role A;
- SQL Login A is a member of Role A;
- Schema B is owned by Role B;
- SQL Login B is a member of Role B;

I'm looking to GRANT CREATE TABLE + CREATE VIEW + CREATE PROCEDURE on Schema A, only to members in Role A and same CREATE statements on Schema B, only to members in Role B. SQL Login B can't CREATE on Schema A.

I've tried the following but I keep stuck as SQL Login B keeps being able to CREATE on Schema A:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[Schema A] to [Role A];
GRANT CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE, CREATE SCHEMA TO [Role A];
```

What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing?" could be the notion of a securable in your `GRANT` statement. Which is to say that because there isn't one, the implicit securable is the database and so you're granting those permissions at that level. What happens if you do `GRANT «permission list» on schema::[Schema A] to [Role A]`?

Comment: was testing here, went for a `DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA :: [Schema A] to [Role B]` but still SQL Login B can CREATE objects in Schema A

Comment: If that's the case, is LoginB somehow db_owner or sysadmin? Check with sys.user_token and sys.login_token (respectively).